# 便利が悪い and 不便 usage

Tags: word-choice

I sometimes come across people (japanese) using the phrase "便利が悪い" and it keeps me wondering why they aren't using 不便 instead.

While 便利が悪い is being roughly translated into "bad convenience / the convenience is bad" and 不便 being "inconvenience" isn't it the same thing?

For example, would "あの場所が不便" and "あの場所の便利が悪い" both be translated into "the location is inconvenient" or is the former "あの場所の便利が悪い" putting more emphasis on the convenience itself being bad, while other things about the location may be good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

便利 usually means "convenient" (na-adj), but it also means "convenience" (noun), according to a dictionary. 買い物の便利が悪い is [listed](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/200714/meaning/m0u/) as a valid example.

That said, I personally never use 便利がいい/悪い, and I think I haven't heard it for years (I live in Tokyo). I vaguely remember a few elderly people were using it when I lived in the western part of Japan many years ago. From a quick google search, it seems to be used mainly in Chugoku and Kyushu regions. I don't think there is a significant difference in meaning.

利便性がいい/悪い and (交通の)便【べん】がいい/悪い are totally fine because 利便性 and 交通の便 only work as nouns.

Comment: I am located in Chikoku so that might explain it.